# Email Internationalization using Velocity/FreeMarker Templates

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, template-engine

How can I achieve i18n using a templating engine such as Velocity or FreeMarker for constructing email body?

Typically people tend to create templates like:

```
<h3>${message.hi} ${user.userName}, ${message.welcome}</h3>
<div>
   ${message.link}<a href="mailto:${user.emailAddress}">${user.emailAddress}</a>.
</div>
```

And have a resource bundle created with properties like:

```
message.hi=Hi
message.welcome=Welcome to Spring!
message.link=Click here to send email.
```

This creates one basic problem: If my `.vm` files becomes large with many lines of text, it becomes tedious to translate and manage each of them in separate resource bundle (`.properties`) files.

What I am trying to do is, have a separate `.vm` file created for each language, something like `mytemplate_en_gb.vm, mytemplate_fr_fr.vm, mytemplate_de_de.vm`and then somehow tell Velocity/Spring to pick up the right one based on the input Locale.

Is this possible in Spring? Or should I be looking at perhaps more simple and obvious alternative approaches?

Note: I have already seen the [Spring tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html#mail-templates) on how to create email bodies using templating engines. But it doesn't seem to answer my question on i18n.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It turns out using one template and multiple language.properties files wins over having multiple templates.

> This creates one basic problem: If my .vm files becomes large with
>   many lines of text, it becomes tedious to translate and manage each of
>   them in separate resource bundle (.properties) files.

It is even harder to maintain if your email structure is duplicated over multiple `.vm` files. Also, one will have to re-invent the fall-back mechanism of resource bundles. Resource bundles try to find the nearest match given a locale. For example, if the locale is `en_GB`, it tries to find the below files in order, falling back to the last one if none of them is available.

- language_en_GB.properties
- language_en.properties
- language.properties

I will post (in detail) what I had to do to simplify reading resource bundles in Velocity templates here.

### Accessing Resource Bundle in a Velocity template

**Spring Configuration**

```xml
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="content/language" />
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">    
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/template/" />
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="velocimacro.library" value="/path/to/macro.vm" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="templateHelper" class="com.foo.template.TemplateHelper">
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
    <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
```

**TemplateHelper Class**

```java
public class TemplateHelper {
    private static final XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(TemplateHelper.class);
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

    public String merge(String templateLocation, Map<String, Object> data, Locale locale) {
        logger.entry(templateLocation, data, locale);

        if (data == null) {
            data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        if (!data.containsKey("messages")) {
            data.put("messages", this.messageSource);
        }

        if (!data.containsKey("locale")) {
            data.put("locale", locale);
        }

        String text =
            VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(this.velocityEngine,
                templateLocation, data);

        logger.exit(text);

        return text;
    }
}
```

**Velocity Template**

```
#parse("init.vm")
#msg("email.hello") ${user} / $user,
#msgArgs("email.message", [${emailId}]).
<h1>#msg("email.heading")</h1>
```

I had to create a short-hand macro, `msg` in order to read from message bundles. It looks like this:

```
#**
 * msg
 *
 * Shorthand macro to retrieve locale sensitive message from language.properties
 *#
#macro(msg $key)
$messages.getMessage($key,null,$locale)
#end

#macro(msgArgs $key, $args)
$messages.getMessage($key,$args.toArray(),$locale)
#end
```

**Resource Bundle**

```
email.hello=Hello
email.heading=This is a localised message
email.message=your email id : {0} got updated in our system.
```

**Usage**

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("user", "Adarsh");
data.put("emailId", "adarsh@email.com");

String body = templateHelper.merge("send-email.vm", data, locale);
```

Comment: This is a really useful post, however, it would be good to be able to pass template values to the internationalization messages like this:

email.hello=hello {0},


#parse("init.vm")
#msg("email.hello" $user.name)

at the moment this does not appear possible, though I can't see why.

Comment: Maybe some one will have this same issue: if you have to send multiple parameters to getMessage, you could use $messages.getMessage($key, $parameters.toArray($arraySample), $locale) where $arraySample has been set in your data map: data.put("arraySample", new Object[0]); I don't know if this is the best solution, but it does the trick because by default, Velocity will send an ArrayList instead of an array

Answer (score 21):

Here's the solution (one template, several resource files) for Freemarker.

**the main program**

```
// defined in the Spring configuration file
MessageSource messageSource;

Configuration config = new Configuration();
// ... additional config settings

// get the template (notice that there is no Locale involved here)
Template template = config.getTemplate(templateName);

Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// the method called "msg" will be available inside the Freemarker template
// this is where the locale comes into play 
model.put("msg", new MessageResolverMethod(messageSource, locale));
```

**MessageResolverMethod class**

```
private class MessageResolverMethod implements TemplateMethodModel {

  private MessageSource messageSource;
  private Locale locale;

  public MessageResolverMethod(MessageSource messageSource, Locale locale) {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
    this.locale = locale;
  }

  @Override
  public Object exec(List arguments) throws TemplateModelException {
    if (arguments.size() != 1) {
      throw new TemplateModelException("Wrong number of arguments");
    }
    String code = (String) arguments.get(0);
    if (code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
      throw new TemplateModelException("Invalid code value '" + code + "'");
    }
    return messageSource.getMessage(code, null, locale);
  }
```

}

**Freemarker template**

```
${msg("subject.title")}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you want to apply your solution on a model-level, inside @ ControllerAdvice-d class just put:  @Autowired private MessageResolverMethod mrm; @ModelAttribute("msg")
    public FormatDateTimeMethodModel formatDateTime() {
        return mrm;
    }

Comment: Wow, thanks ! Finally got to reduce my templates to one with this code.

Comment: Note that the `TemplateMethodModel` is now deprecated and `TemplateMethodModelEx` is recommended instead. Additionally, I had to cast the argument to a String via the `toString()` method as opposed to using explicit `(String)` casting.