# Using parameters/{0} substitutions when doing i18n in Velocity

Tags: velocity

So I have a couple of messages in my property file that looks like this:

```
email.errordetailstemplate.subject=An error occurred in {0}
email.errordetailstemplate.errordetails=--- Error details ---
```

Going by the [recommendations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605828/email-internationalization-using-velocity-freemarker-templates) I can then easily do this:

```
$messages.getMessage("email.errordetailstemplate.errordetails", null, $locale)
```

...but what I would love to be able to do is to be able to do substitution of {0} like this:

```
$messages.getMessage("email.errordetailstemplate.subject", $productname, $locale)
```

I'm sure it's possible, but I just can't figure out the proper syntax. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5513067

Just using this syntax should work:

```
$messages.getMessage("email.errordetailstemplate.errordetails", [$productName], $locale)
```

I say "should" because my need disappeared, and so I haven't had a reason to verify.